# php curly braces groups

Tags: php

Is there a function or regex or anything to group items by a `{` and `}` tag? so it should group items by the opening tag { and the closing tag }. but be careful, there are also groups inside parent groups like so:

```
group {
   text1
   group2 { 
      text2
   }
}
```

so basically think of it like php, you make an opening tag, you need to close it with a closing tag, curly braces in php's case.

I just need it to like `substr()` each group into an associative array somehow, except I cant figure it out with the whole, "group inside a parent group".

Edit:
I'm trying to make my own syntax highlighter for learning purposes, and I thought grouping would be best. Yes I know there is a php function for highlighting but... this is for educational purposes.

Comment: This is already non-trivial. What's the use case?

Comment: Have you forgotten that you already asked this question, and even received an answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650414/php-curly-braces-into-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php curly braces into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650414/php-curly-braces-into-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through each occurrence and create a stack of scopes, pushing a new scope onto the stack with each `{` and popping a scope with each `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this to parse some code or something? You may need to write a recursive function similar to how (parentheses) in math would be used

(7*((A+B)*C))

Comment: could you expand on this or is there a link you can point me to, to read im not sure how to read the math above.