# Navigating Stanford CoreNLP parsing results

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp

Stanford Core NLP parser generates the following output for the sentence:

```
"He didn't get a reply" 

(ROOT
(S
(NP (PRP He))
(VP (VBD did) (RB n’t)
(VP (VB get)
(NP (DT a) (NN reply))))
(. .)))
```

I need a way to navigate it i.e. extra tags easily and find children and parents. Currently I am doing it manually (counting parenthesis). I wonder if there is a Python library that can do parenthesis counting for me or even better like Beautiful Soup or Scrapy would let me work with objects.

If there is no tool, what is the best way to traverse a sentence and get all tags? I am guessing I would need to create some sort of tag object with list containing children tag objects.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this python script](https://gist.github.com/pib/240957) for solving the problem with success.

The script can be used to convert Stanford Core NLP's Lisp-like parse tree format into a nested python list structure.

You can also convert the nested list further using something like [Anytree](https://github.com/c0fec0de/anytree) into a more navigable Python data structure, which will also allow you to print out the tree either in text or as an image.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like LISP.  Writing a Lisp program to traverse it and extract what you want seems easy.

You could also convert it into a list in python and process in python:

```
from pyparsing import OneOrMore, nestedExpr
nlpdata = '(ROOT (S (NP (PRP He)) (VP (VBD did) (RB n\'t) (VP (VB get) (NP (DT a) (NN reply)))) (. .)))'
data = OneOrMore(nestedExpr()).parseString(nlpdata)
print data
# [['ROOT', ['S', ['NP', ['PRP', 'He']], ['VP', ['VBD', 'did'], ['RB', "n't"], ['VP', ['VB', 'get'], ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'reply']]]], ['.', '.']]]]
```

Note that I had to escape the quote in "n't"

Answer (score 1):

My approach to navigating the output was not to try parsing the string, but instead to build an object and deserialize. Then you have the object available natively.

The output shown in the question is produced using an option on the pipeline called "prettyPrint". I changed that to "jsonPrint" to get JSON output instead. I was then able to take the output and generate a class from it (VS can do a Paste-Special option to generate a class from JSON, or there are online resources like http://json2csharp.com/). The resultant class looked like this:

```
public class BasicDependency
    {
        public string dep { get; set; }
        public int governor { get; set; }
        public string governorGloss { get; set; }
        public int dependent { get; set; }
        public string dependentGloss { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnhancedDependency
    {
        public string dep { get; set; }
        public int governor { get; set; }
        public string governorGloss { get; set; }
        public int dependent { get; set; }
        public string dependentGloss { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnhancedPlusPlusDependency
    {
        public string dep { get; set; }
        public int governor { get; set; }
        public string governorGloss { get; set; }
        public int dependent { get; set; }
        public string dependentGloss { get; set; }
    }

    public class Token
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string word { get; set; }
        public string originalText { get; set; }
        public string lemma { get; set; }
        public int characterOffsetBegin { get; set; }
        public int characterOffsetEnd { get; set; }
        public string pos { get; set; }
        public string ner { get; set; }
        public string speaker { get; set; }
        public string before { get; set; }
        public string after { get; set; }
        public string normalizedNER { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sentence
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string parse { get; set; }
        public List<BasicDependency> basicDependencies { get; set; }
        public List<EnhancedDependency> enhancedDependencies { get; set; }
        public List<EnhancedPlusPlusDependency> enhancedPlusPlusDependencies { get; set; }
        public List<Token> tokens { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Sentence> sentences { get; set; }
    }
```

*Note: Unfortunately this technique did not work out for coref annotations. The JSON did not convert properly to a class. I'm working on that now. This model was built from output using the annotators "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse".

My code, only slightly changed from the sample code, looks like this (note the "pipeline.jsonPrint"):

```
public static string LanguageAnalysis(string sourceText)
        {
            string json = "";
            // Path to the folder with models extracted from stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar
            var jarRoot = @"..\..\..\..\packages\Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP.3.7.0.1\";

            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");

            // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
            var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
            var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);

            // Annotation
            var annotation = new Annotation(sourceText);
            pipeline.annotate(annotation);

            // Result - JSON Print
            using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
            {
                pipeline.jsonPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
                json = stream.toString();
                stream.close();
            }

            return json;
        }
```

It seems to deserialize nicely with code like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
string sourceText = "My text document to parse.";
string json = Analysis.LanguageAnalysis(sourceText);
RootObject document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Now that I'm working with the resultant object, I realise my answer does not actually answer the question! The parser output is still supplied in that same format as one string, called "Parse". I now join @user1700890 in looking for a way to parse it!

Comment: Looking further, I see this question, which appears to be the same, and has an answer using php: [PHP and NLP: Nested parenthesis (parser output) to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917161/php-and-nlp-nested-parenthesis-parser-output-to-array)